# edit form with some disable field

Tags: symfony, twig

i have a form with some field  and i want user edit only some field and the other field must be only visible .

In my controller i have the form

```
$element = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Element')->find($id_element);
     $form = $this->createForm(ElementType::class, $element, array('user' => $user));


code here`$form->handleRequest($request);
```

Now in my twig file

```
  {{ form_start(form) }}

  {{ form_widget(form.element,{ 'attr':{'disabled':'disabled'}}) }}
```

In this way when i click submit button say not focusable field so i add

```
{{ form_widget(form.element,{ 'attr':{'disabled':'disabled'}}) }}
```

but when i save the field element in database become null

How i can do it ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `readonly` attribute for it

```
{{ form_widget(form.element,{ 'attr':{'readonly':'1'}}) }}
```

Values of disabled controls are not submitted with a form.
https://www.w3.org/TR/PR-html40-971107/interact/forms.html#h-17.7

Comment: there is the same problem form.element not focusable

Comment: why it should be focusable if it must be only visible and not editable?

Comment: i don't want it be focusable .. i want only it visible but in this way don't submit the form

Comment: I don't understand you. Add full code of the form `ElementType::class` and twig template to the question.